# Слитное/раздельное написание частицы НЕ

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Как следует писать «НЕ» в предложении «В числе не?явившихся на заседание были Петров и Сергеев»?
Знаю, что раздельно, но почему? Какое здесь правило?

---

Answer (score 3):

> В числе **не явившихся** на заседание были Петров и Сергеев

"Не явившихся" - причастие с зависимым словом ("на заседание"), поэтому раздельно.

Более подробно можете посмотреть в Гугле, набрав "Розенталь частица не с причастиями" или "Розенталь правописание не с причастями".

Удачи!

Comment: А можете еще подсказать? Вот в этом тесте http://www.primavista.ru/test/znaete-li-vy-russkij-yazyk/ 4-й вопрос: что там не так с именами?

Comment: Уберем "на заседание" – и тогда пишем слитно? Едва ли. По крайней мере, раздельное написание все равно возможно.

Comment: @Niemand - интересно. Я не подумал про то, что может подразумеваться зависимое слово. Нужно было побольше почитать..

Answer (score 0):

А там отрицание чувствуется. Не чувствуется? Тогда объясняем так: зависимое слово либо присутствует, либо подразумевается. Нельзя быть просто "неявившимся".